# Does changing ToList to ToListAsync indeed solve "second operation started on this context"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

After running my code well for a long time, finally I get errors like:

InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext, however instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe. This could also be caused by a nested query being evaluated on the client, if this is the case rewrite the query avoiding nested invocations.

The error happens every time on a line with:

```
context FromSql with ToList
```

If I change this to:

```
await context FromSql ToListAsync
```

and change the method to:

```
async Task<>
```

Is this indeed the right solution?

-------------UPDATE---------------------
I have a controller from which other controllers inherit

```
public abstract class PortalController  : Controller
    {
        protected readonly UserManager<SuUserModel> _userManager;
        protected readonly ILanguageRepository _language;
        protected readonly SuDbContext _context;

        public  PortalController(UserManager<SuUserModel> userManager
                                                , ILanguageRepository language
                                                , SuDbContext context
            )
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _language = language;
            _context = context;
        }
```

Here I define the context.

In the controllers that inherit this it looks like:

```
 public class ContentTypeController : PortalController
    {
        private readonly IContentTypeLanguageRepository _contentTypeLanguage;
        private readonly IContentTypeRepository _contentType;

        public ContentTypeController(UserManager<SuUserModel> userManager
            , IContentTypeLanguageRepository ContentTypeLanguage
            , IContentTypeRepository contentType
            , ILanguageRepository language
                        , SuDbContext context
) : base(userManager, language, context)
        {
            _contentTypeLanguage = ContentTypeLanguage;
            _contentType = contentType;
        }
```

Before, I didn't use this base controller though.

Also, I changed the Startup.cs connection string with ServiceLifetime.Transient, but doesn't help:

```
services.AddDbContext<SuDbContext>(options => {options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("SuConnectionString"));}, ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

--------------------------UPDATE------------------------------

Trying to figure out more about this.
In my controller I call the following method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var CurrentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

    base.Initializing();

    var parameter = new SqlParameter("@LanguageId", CurrentUser.DefaultLanguageId);

    var OrganizationType = _context.ZdbObjectIndexGet.FromSql("OrganizationTypeIndexGet @LanguageId", parameter).ToList();
    return View(OrganizationType);
```

This calls from the base controller:

```
public async void Initializing()
{
    var CurrentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    var DefaultLanguageID = CurrentUser.DefaultLanguageId;

    var UICustomizationArray = new UICustomization(_context);
    ViewBag.Terms = UICustomizationArray.UIArray(this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(), this.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), DefaultLanguageID);
    Menus a = new Menus(_context);

    ViewBag.menuItems = a.TopMenu(DefaultLanguageID);
    return;
}
```

And this calls the UIArray method in class UICustomization:

```
public class UICustomization
{
    private readonly SuDbContext _context;

    public UICustomization(SuDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    public string[] UIArray(string Controller, string Action, int languageId)
    {
        //UI Customization
        SqlParameter[] parameters =
                 {
                new SqlParameter("@Controller", Controller)
                , new SqlParameter("@Action", Action)
                , new SqlParameter("@LanguageId", languageId)

            };
        var CustomizationFromDb = _context.ZdbLayoutTermList.FromSql("UITermLanguageSelect @Controller, @Action, @LanguageID", parameters).ToList();
        int NoOfTerms = CustomizationFromDb.Count();
        String[] CustomTerms = new String[NoOfTerms];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (var x in CustomizationFromDb)
        {
            CustomTerms[i] = x.Name;
            i++;
        }
        return CustomTerms;
        //UI Customization
    }
```

With the first Method when I run that, I get the error. So, I assume it should be part of this controller / base controller and the class that is being called:

Comment: I don't think so, as the first one just has the thread wait for a response back from the DB, while the second does it asynchronously. You'll need to see if you are using the same context instance across threads.

Comment: Am I correct that with the setup of the controllers as added in above, I would create each time a new instance?

Comment: Yes, it would be a different instance each time since the lifetime is transient.

Comment: So, if I call within the same instance of a controller in the same method use 2 times that context I might have a problem?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If you do multi-threading in the controller, you could run into this issue.

Comment: Still, based on that, it shouldn't happen. I don't have context static defined. Btw, the project I am working on is a volunteer project for a community focusing on sustainability.

Comment: @juunas  I also dropped you a linkedin message

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if I call a method that has an await statements in it, I also have to use the await when calling the actual method.